# R : Number of black pixels in a 18 x 18 matrix with only 1 black pixel neighbour

Tags: r, artificial-intelligence

I want to calculate the number of black pixels in a 18 x 18 matrix with only 1 black pixel neighbour. neighbours include N, NE, E, SE, S, SW, W, NW of the pixel.

so far I've got:

neigh_1_function <- function(matrix){
......
}

aka nothing, please help me :(

Comment: What does this have to do with artificial intelligence ... ??

Comment: it will eventually be used to identify letters, faces and symbols as part of a university project in my AI module

Comment: OK.  As warned below, if you try to build this into a system that is iterating many times (e.g. over 18x18 neighbourhoods of a large image), it will be **slow**.

Comment: Just reminding you that if you use this code in your project you should credit the source ...

Comment: Greetings! Please provide a reproducible dataset. You can do so by using `dput` on your data. Details can be found here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 1):

(I hope I'm not doing your homework for you ...)

This is called the *Moore neighbo(u)rhood*, in case that helps find information. The solution below is not super-efficient; if you need to do this for a large number of iterations or a much bigger matrix you should probably look for some C++ code as in [this blog post](https://fronkonstin.com/2021/01/02/neighborhoods-experimenting-with-cyclic-cellular-automata/)) (although it implements *cyclic* neighbourhoods that wrap around the edges of the matrix). I have some fancier/more efficient methods that make use of sparse matrix multiplication documented [here](https://math.mcmaster.ca/%7Ebolker/classes/m747/notes/durrettlevin.Rnw) ([PDF](https://math.mcmaster.ca/%7Ebolker/classes/m747/notes/durrettlevin.pdf); [utility functions](https://math.mcmaster.ca/%7Ebolker/classes/m747/notes/nbrmatfuns.R)).

I think the following code works but I haven't tested it much.  It would be good to try it out on a small matrix that's easy to hand-test to start:

```r
## matrix of relative row/col positions of neighbours
nbr_mat <- as.matrix(expand.grid(c(-1,0,1), c(-1,0,1)))
nbr_mat <- nbr_mat[-5,] ## don't count self
## return number of neighbours of matrix element (i,j)
pixel_nbrs <- function(i,j) {
   ## compute absolute row/col positions of nbrs
   nbr_ind <- sweep(nbr_mat, MARGIN = 1, STAT = c(i,j), FUN = "+")
   ## identify rows corresponding to positions within matrix bounds\
   ## (refers to *global* N value)
   in_bounds <- apply(nbr_ind <= N & nbr_ind >= 1, 1, all)
   ## extract values (refers to *global* M)
   pix_vals <- M[nbr_ind[in_bounds,]]
   ## count number of nbrs
   return(sum(pix_vals))
}
## vectorize so we can run it for multiple {i,j}
vpix <- Vectorize(pixel_nbrs)
```

Simulated example:

```r
set.seed(101)
N <- 18
M <- matrix(sample(0:1, 18^2, replace= TRUE), 18, 18)
```

Tabulate:

```r
## apply counting function for all combinations of row/col inds
nbrs <- outer(1:N,1:N, vpix)
## count number with exactly 1 nbr
sum(nbrs == 1)
```

Comment: If this solved your problem you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it (if it didn't, maybe leave a comment about why it didn't work for you?)